# Error generating code from FixML 5.0 SP2

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, fix-protocol

I'm using the [Fix standard](http://www.fixprotocol.org/documents/5915/fixmlschema_FIX.5.0SP2_Errata_20110818.zip) as the source (file fixml-main-5-0-SP2.xsd).

I get the following error when trying to generate C# code using Liquid XML Data Binder:

```
"The namespace 'http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2/METADATA'
provided differs from the schema's targetNamespace
'http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2'."
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FixML standard appears to contain a small error.

All the schemas contain the attribute
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2/METADATA fixml-metadata-5-0-SP2.xsd"

However the document "fixml-metadata-5-0-SP2.xsd" has a targetnamespace of "http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2" not "http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2/METADATA" as stated in the schemaLocation.

Changing the targetnamespace in the file "fixml-metadata-5-0-SP2.xsd" to "http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2/METADATA" resolves the issue.

If you are in contact with the FixML team I would suggest you notify them of the change required.

Comment: Yes this works, but I have no link to FixML team so I cannot tell them.